# Change case and reorder string fields in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, case

I have created the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
ds1 = {'Name':["CARO QUINTERO, Miguel Angel","CHANG, Ping Yun","GILBOA, Joseph"]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=ds1)
```

Which looks like this:

```
                          Name
0  CARO QUINTERO, Miguel Angel
1              CHANG, Ping Yun
2               GILBOA, Joseph
```

So, the text before the comma is the "last name", whilst the text after the comma is the first name (s).

I need to create a new column (called `matchKey`) such that:

- it contains first and last name (in that order)
- the first letter of the first name and last name is in upper case.

So, from the example above, the resulting dataframe would look like this:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Does anybody know how to do to it in pandas?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/By1Uz.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with [`Series.str.title`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.title.html):

```
df1['matchKey']=df1['Name'].str.replace(r'^(.*),\s*(.*)$',r'\2 \1', regex=True).str.title()
print (df1)
                          Name                    matchKey
0  CARO QUINTERO, Miguel Angel  Miguel Angel Caro Quintero
1              CHANG, Ping Yun              Ping Yun Chang
2               GILBOA, Joseph               Joseph Gilboa
```

Or [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
s = df1['Name'].str.extract(r'^(.*),(.*)$')
df1['matchKey'] = s[1].str.cat( s[0].str.title(), sep=' ')
print (df1)
                          Name                     matchKey
0  CARO QUINTERO, Miguel Angel   Miguel Angel Caro Quintero
1              CHANG, Ping Yun               Ping Yun Chang
2               GILBOA, Joseph                Joseph Gilboa
```